# Windows 10: How to avoid MS Office to be started?

Tags: windows-10, office365

In my family there is a person using Windows 10 and a non-Microsoft office suite.

On the computer, there is some "Microsoft 365" pre-installed which is not "registered". This means that you can open documents read-only (but you can't save) and when starting Microsoft Word, annoying messages are shown that you should buy a license.

I already renamed `word.exe` (or `winword.exe`?) so this file cannot be started accidentally.

I also assigned text documents (`.doc` and `.docx`) to the third-party office suite.

Other document types (like `.odt`) were already assigned to the third-party office suite before.

**My problem:**

Since the last Windows update, even double-clicking document files that were *never* assigned to Word (like `.odt`) seem to open Microsoft Word instead of the other office suite as I would expect it.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

I could of course manually assign file extensions like `.odt` to the third-party office suite, however, I fear that the next Windows update will change these settings again!

I don't want to uninstall "Microsoft 365" completely because I fear that there are some programs depend on `.dll` files of Microsoft Office to be installed on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Office may be starting because it is not registered and is trying to get you to register it.

1. Uninstalling it should not break any non-Office DLLs and is an option open to you. You can always reinstall Office at a later time.
2. You can try preventing it from starting.

To prevent Office unregistered from starting, I suggest you look at Autoruns (Microsoft SysInternals).

You can try the Startup Tab in Task Manager but SysInternals is more comprehensive.

Be careful of One Drive. One Drive comes with Office so if you are not using Office, you may wish to not use One Drive as well.

Once Office is not starting, you may wish to reverse some of the changes you made earlier.

I posted a screen shot of Autoruns. I have Office activated so it does not start automatically. In Autoruns you can try unchecking the Program you do not want to start and then see it that works. You may need to delete the startup item.

[image]

Comment: Auto-Starting is not my problem: I looked up the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.odt`: That registry key shows that the file extension `.odt` is connected to Microsoft 365. This means that Microsoft 365 will be started whenever a `.odt` file will be double-clicked and the other office suite is not started. I could of course change this but I fear that the next update would overwrite the registry settings again.

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer, uninstalling Office is the best approach since you do not use it and have not registered it.

Comment: Well, my fear is that my family member is using it: Maybe the family member who owns the computer has registered Teams or Skype or she uses some other program which accesses the MS 365 DLLs. By un-installing MS 365 those programs would not work any longer.

Comment: You normally cannot make an unregistered program work properly. It nags you. Either register it or uninstall it. You can always reinstall if you want it and register it at that time. I made that clear for you in my answer.